# Classifying different points MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, classification

I have a random set of points that i want to plot into different classes (colours).
I know how i can classify them according to different functions and I have shown an example below. 
The problem is that I know the classification regions I want, from (0,0.1) to (0.7,1) for example but i don't know what functions would achieve this or how to work them out.

```
x = rand(500,1);
y = rand(500,1);
g(:,1) = 1-x;
g(:,2)= 1 -y;
[~,la] = max(g'); % find the labels
figure, hold on 
plot(x(la==1),y(la==1),'k.','MarkerSize',8)
plot(x(la==2),y(la==2),'r.','MarkerSize',8)
grid on,xlabel('x_1'),ylabel('x_2')
```

This is an example using some basic functions to create the plot below. At the moment I am using trial and error but how could I use the same idea as above but plotting regions where I know the endpoints like I mentioned above.

[image]

EDIT:
Using am304 solution. I have got the correct output, but with a more complicated plot like this it seems like it could be simplified a lot.

```
x = rand(500,1);
y = rand(500,1);
p = polyfit([0 0.7],[0.1 1],1);
p2 = polyfit([0.4 1],[1 0],1);
p3 = polyfit([0 1],[0.3 0.6],1);

figure
hold on
plot(x,y,'m.','MarkerSize',8)
plot(x(y>=polyval(p,x) & y<=polyval(p2,x) & y>=polyval(p3,x)),y(y>=polyval(p,x) & y<=polyval(p2,x) &   y>=polyval(p3,x)),'y.','MarkerSize',8)
plot(x(y>=polyval(p2,x) & y<=polyval(p,x) & y>=polyval(p3,x)),y(y>=polyval(p2,x) & y<=polyval(p,x) & y>=polyval(p3,x)),'r.','MarkerSize',8)
plot(x(y<=polyval(p3,x) & y<=polyval(p,x) & y<=polyval(p2,x)),y(y<=polyval(p3,x) & y<=polyval(p,x) & y<=polyval(p2,x)),'g.','MarkerSize',8)
plot([0 0.7],[0.1 1],'k-')
plot([0.4 1],[1 0],'k-')
plot([0 1],[0.3 0.6],'k-')
grid on,xlabel('x_1'),ylabel('x_2')
```

Comment: Your solution looks fine at first sight. What trial and error are you talking about?

Comment: The calculations here are for the different coloured sections:

g(:,1) = 1-x;
g(:,2)= 1 -y;


The trial and error is to get the plot that i want ( i know what points i want my lines to go through) i don't know what I should replace 1-x and 1-y with

Comment: @Tomsmith have you look at my answer? Does that not do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want something like that:

```
>> p = polyfit([0 0.7],[0.1 1],1)
p =

      1.2857         0.1

>> figure
>> hold on
>> plot(x(y>=p(1)*x+p(2)),y(y>=p(1)*x+p(2)),'k.','MarkerSize',8)
>> plot(x(y<=p(1)*x+p(2)),y(y<=p(1)*x+p(2)),'r.','MarkerSize',8)
>> plot([0 0.7],[0.1 1],'g-')
>> grid on,xlabel('x_1'),ylabel('x_2')
```

This is what I get in Octave:

[image]

**EDIT following discussion in comments**:

There's not much more simplifying yo do, other than the following to make it more readable and debuggable in the future:

```
x = rand(500,1);
y = rand(500,1);
p = polyfit([0 0.7],[0.1 1],1);
p2 = polyfit([0.4 1],[1 0],1);
p3 = polyfit([0 1],[0.3 0.6],1);

figure
hold on
plot(x,y,'m.','MarkerSize',8)
idx1 = y>=polyval(p,x) & y<=polyval(p2,x) & y>=polyval(p3,x);
idx2 = y>=polyval(p2,x) & y<=polyval(p,x) & y>=polyval(p3,x);
idx3 = y<=polyval(p3,x) & y<=polyval(p,x) & y<=polyval(p2,x);
plot(x(idx1),y(idx1),'y.','MarkerSize',8)
plot(x(idx2),y(idx2),'r.','MarkerSize',8)
plot(x(idx3),y(idx3),'g.','MarkerSize',8)
plot([0 0.7],[0.1 1],'k-')
plot([0.4 1],[1 0],'k-')
plot([0 1],[0.3 0.6],'k-')
grid on,xlabel('x_1'),ylabel('x_2')
```

This results in the following figure:

[image]

Comment: PS: you could replace `y>=p(1)*x+p(2)` by `y>=polyval(p,x)`, and the same for the other inequality.

Comment: sorry I thought I had replied. Please see the updated first post as I could not fit it in the comments.